# Get Month and date from a hardcoded date value

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
select convert(varchar(5),getdate(), 100)
```

If you run the above query, the result is 'Jun 1', so the first three letters of the month, a space and the first digit of the date. But if I replace getdate() function with a hardcoded value such as the query below, the result change drastically.

```
select convert(varchar(5), '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000', 100)
```

How can the query be written if the result must be the first three characters of the month and two digit date *with no space*

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
DECLARE @date DATE;


set @date = '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000';
select convert(varchar(6),@date, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

Prior to `format()`, there was `datename()`.  This should do what you want:

```
select left(datename(month, getdate()), 3) + right('00' + datename(day, getdate()), 2)
```

You can also use your method, but you need to replace the spaces:

```
select replace(replace(convert(varchar(6), cast('2018-05-01 00:00:00.000' as date), 100), '  ', '0'), ' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

That because you are passing `varchar` or `string` type date `'2018-05-01 00:00:00.000'` that something like :

```
select left('2018-05-01 00:00:00.000', 5)
```

If you want same result then you need cast them as reasonable format

```
select convert(varchar(6),cast('2018-06-01' as date), 100)
```

I have misread the *last* line, if you want no space then just simple use `replace()`

```
select replace(replace(convert(varchar(6), cast('2018-06-01' as date), 100), '  ', '0'), ' ', '0')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your timestamp to date, and then format it any way you like:

`select format(cast('2018-05-01 00:00:00.000' as date), 'MMMdd')`

Comment: You are returning month and year with a space, that is not what OP is asking for, it should be
`select format(convert(date, '2018-05-01 00:00:00.000'), 'MMMdd');`

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.